# How do I get my Roccat Lua mouse fully working on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit?

Tags: permissions, mouse

I added [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~berfenger/+archive/ubuntu/roccat) and installed the roccat-tools package as per [this guide](http://roccat.sourceforge.net/) and added my user to the roccat group. I could run luaconfig and make changes but when I clicked "Store in device" I received the message "Error creating directory: permission denied". I tried running luaconfig from a terminal with `sudo luaconfig` and now I can save the configuration to my mouse!

Now, after running luaconfig with sudo and then trying to run it without sudo, I receive the error message "Failed to create file '/var/lib/roccat/luba/actual.rmp.V47KRX': Permision denied". Should I grant read+write access to the directory /var/lib/roccat/ to my username? If I understand the /var directory correctly, these are temporary files and so my permissions change would likely not stick after a reboot.

I can confirm that the module for my mouse is loaded:

```
$ cat /proc/modules | grep "lua"
hid_roccat_lua 12789 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
hid_roccat_common 13791 1 hid_roccat_lua, Live 0x0000000000000000
hid 106148 2 hid_roccat_lua,usbhid, Live 0x0000000000000000
```

Also, the button on the mouse that is supposed to change the CPI (DPI) does not work. I can change it with the software, but now with the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing first: Don't ever run the tools as root! Linux is not Windows, even if it's Ubuntu.

Other things you need to know:

After adding yourself to group roccat you need to at least relogin for the new membership to get applied.

The device needs a replug, so that udev can apply the newly installed rules.

Now do this:

Delete the files that have been created with the wrong rights:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/roccat
```

Rebuild the folder with

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/roccat
sudo chown root:roccat /var/lib/roccat
sudo chmod 2770 /var/lib/roccat
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick! After some playing around with settings, the CPI button is also now working. Thank you, you are awesome!